# Getting empty answer Mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, emptydatatext

Hi there im having some issues with MongoDb i have a CRUD and this is the code im using

First the POJO:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "Informacion")
public class Informacion {

//Declaration code

public Informacion(Pais pais, Date fechaCreacion, String nombre, Boolean sexo,
                   Date fechaNacimiento, List<Preferencias> preferencias, String numTelefono, String usuario,
                   List<RedesSociales> redes, String contraseniaTW, String contraseniaFB, String contraseniaIG,
                   Grupo grupo, String paqChip, String email, String contraseniaMail, String fuente,
                   Date fechaRecarga) {
    this.pais = pais;
    this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    this.preferencias = preferencias;
    this.numTelefono = numTelefono;
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.redes = redes;
    this.contraseniaTW = contraseniaTW;
    this.contraseniaFB = contraseniaFB;
    this.contraseniaIG = contraseniaIG;
    this.grupo = grupo;
    this.paqChip = paqChip;
    this.email = email;
    this.contraseniaMail = contraseniaMail;
    this.fuente = fuente;
    this.fechaRecarga = fechaRecarga;
}
```

}

Now the DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface informacionRepo extends MongoRepository<Informacion,String> {
     Informacion findByIdInformacion(String id);
}
```

And the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Informacion")
public class InformacionControlador {
@Autowired
private informacionRepo informacioRepo;

public InformacionControlador(informacionRepo informacioRepo) {
    this.informacioRepo = informacioRepo;
}


@GetMapping("/Listar")
public List<Informacion> getAll(){
    List<Informacion> info = this.informacioRepo.findAll();
    System.out.println(info.isEmpty());
    return info;
}


@PutMapping
public void insert(@RequestBody Informacion informacion){
    this.informacioRepo.insert(informacion);
}


public void update(@RequestBody Informacion informacion){
    this.informacioRepo.save(informacion);
}


@DeleteMapping("/Listar/{id}")
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") String id){
    this.informacioRepo.deleteById(id);
}

@GetMapping("/Listar/{id}")
public Informacion getById(@PathVariable("id") String id){
    Informacion info =  this.informacioRepo.findByIdInformacion(id);
    return info;
}
}
```

Im using POSTMAN to test the methods above but im getting empty answers, the data is already set on the Database, im using a method call seeder that fills the data also y check it with robo mongo and the data is there but still getting empty answers also when i try the insert method i get 403 error.
Thanks for your help
[This is the answer seen from the web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qL4p.png)

Comment: Are you sure that you have two records not empty in your DB?

Comment: Yes i am, btw finally solve the problem my fail was taht im using the annotation @Data from lombok but i didnt enable annotation processing :p

Comment: It's OK so you should add your answer and close this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that im using the annotation @Data from lombok but i didnt enable annotation processing in the IDE just enable it and works :D